# android apk size greater than source code size

Tags: android

I found apk size (42MB) greater than source code size (1.4MB), so I check the res folder:

In source code, it only define:
res/values/strings.xml

But in apk after unzip:

```
anim/                color/                drawable-ldpi-v4/            drawable-v21/        drawable-xxxhdpi-v4/  layout-sw600dp-v13/
animator/            color-night-v31/      drawable-ldrtl/              drawable-v23/        interpolator/         layout-sw600dp-v31/
animator-ldrtl-v11/  color-night-v8/       drawable-ldrtl-hdpi-v17/     drawable-v26/        interpolator-v21/     layout-v21/
animator-v11/        color-v23/            drawable-ldrtl-mdpi-v17/     drawable-v31/        interpolator-v31/     layout-v26/
animator-v21/        color-v31/            drawable-ldrtl-xhdpi-v17/    drawable-v33/        layout/               layout-v31/
anim-ldrtl-v31/      drawable/             drawable-ldrtl-xxhdpi-v17/   drawable-watch-v20/  layout-land/          layout-v33/
anim-v21/            drawable-anydpi-v21/  drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi-v17/  drawable-xhdpi-v4/   layout-land-v31/      layout-watch-v20/
anim-v31/            drawable-hdpi-v4/     drawable-mdpi-v4/            drawable-xxhdpi-v4/  layout-ldrtl-v17/     xml/
```

This app is a service, no UI used.

What's the reason it included so many res stuff in apk? How can I remove it?

Comment: Do you get the same result when you use app bundle?

Answer (score 0):

> I found apk size (42MB) greater than source code size (1.4MB)

That is normal.

> What's the reason it included so many res stuff in apk?

Most will come from third-party libraries.

> This app is a service, no UI used

That may become a problem when you go to distribute it.

> How can I remove it?

Start by removing any third-party libraries that you do not need. After that, enable R8 on your release builds, in particular [enabling resource shrinking](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#shrink-resources). That will remove resources that seem to be unused.

Comment: Awesome answer, but after enable R8, app will crash. Is R8 a matrue technique in current release?

Comment: @lucky1928: "after enable R8, app will crash" -- you probably need to [teach R8 about additional code to keep](https://developer.android.com/build/shrink-code#keep-code) that it cannot infer. "Is R8 a matrue technique in current release?" -- yes.